# How to create public class method for intent in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am newbie in app development.In my project have lot of Explicit Intent so i want to make a public method which argument contains conext or a class where i want to jump but it's not working is there have who know the proper solution for it.

Here is my method where i call my public intent class.

```
    private void startActivityMethod() {
    if (progressStatus == 100) {
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            if (sp.getString(Constants.userType, "").equals("student")) {
                Constants.explicitIntent(SplashActivity.this, studentMainActivity.class);
            } else if (sp.getString(Constants.userType, "").equals("faculties")) {
                Constants.explicitIntent(SplashActivity.this, facultiesMainActivity.class);
            }
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my public class method for intent.

```
    public static void explicitIntent(Context context, Class<?> intentClass) {
    Intent intent =new Intent(context,intentClass);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `startActivity` to launch the `intent`

```
public static void explicitIntent(Context context, Class<?> intentClass) {
    Intent intent =new Intent(context, intentClass);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```